# Powershell "Invoke-Sqlcmd2" not connecting with Windows Account credentials

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, windows-authentication

I have a script which calls `Invoke-Sqlcmd2`

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'xxxxxxx' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('domain\someuser', $password)

$resultListTable = Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -Credential $cred -query $query -ServerInstance "SERVER" -Database ZZZZ -As "DataTable"
```

which fails with an error message

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'domain\someuser'."

My DBA reports to me that he can see the error from the server that looks like this:

> Login failed for user 'domain\someuser' Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication.

The documentation for Invoke-SqlCmd2 at ( https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/Invoke-SqlCmd2/blob/master/Invoke-SqlCmd2/Public/Invoke-SqlCmd2.ps1 ) indicates that both windows and sql authentication are supported. (I've tried with just sql credentials, and that works fine, but I need to use the windows credentials I have for business reasons).  And I've seen (somewhere, can't find it right now) that simply providing a backslash in the username is sufficient for it (presumably the `System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection` object) to select windows authentication. Unfortunately, that is not the behavior I am seeing.

Is there something else I need to be doing with the call to make Windows authentication kick in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the code actually does though is:

```
if ($Credential) {
  $CSBuilder["Trusted_Connection"] = $false
  $CSBuilder["User ID"] = $Credential.UserName
  $CSBuilder["Password"] = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
}
else {
  $CSBuilder["Integrated Security"] = $true
}
```

(see [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sqlcollaborative/Invoke-SqlCmd2/master/Invoke-SqlCmd2/Public/Invoke-SqlCmd2.ps1))

...so basically if you supply a credential then it's assumed to be a SQL Server login, not a windows login (because trusted connection is set to false).

N.B. You've inherently misunderstood how SQL Server's authentication works. Windows Auth to SQL Server is done implicitly on the basis of the *current* logged in user. If integrated/trusted authentication is set to be on in the connection string, then SQL will automatically use the context of the windows user making the connection to determine the user's identity. You can't specify a different windows user. This applies to all SQL Server clients. If you want to log onto SQL as a different user then you need to run the powershell script under that user account.

Comment: so the documentation is misleading, in that it suggests passing a credential object with windows authentication info ought to work?

Comment: Arguably. I think it's ambiguous, certainly. But if you know how SQL Server's authentication works you would understand. I guess you'd have to make a suggestion to the maintainers to make it clearer though, it wouldn't do any harm, since it's non-obvious if you're not familiar with the underlying tech.